# Select Max And Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have SQL Server 2012 database, I need to query database and get results relevant to MAX(Rule_ID) AND MAX(CI_ID)

But i cant get results relevant to MAX(CI_ID) all CI_ID versions are in results.

```
USE CM_T01
SELECT Max_id, MAX(CIVersion), Netbios_Name0, RuleName, RuleDescription, prereifiedvalue, complianceState
FROM v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT CI_ID,Rule_ID, Rulename,  RuleDescription,criteria, MAX(Rule_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY Rulename) AS Max_id
from v_cirules
where rulename like '%Account lockout duration%' AND RuleDescription like '%applicable%'
group by Rule_ID,RuleName, RuleDescription,CI_ID,Criteria) as v_CIRules 
ON v_CIRules.CI_ID = v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus.CI_ID
INNER JOIN v_R_System 
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus.ItemKey
LEFT JOIN v_CICurrentRuleDetail 
ON v_CICurrentRuleDetail.CurrentComplianceStatusID = v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus.CI_CurrentComplianceStatusID
where netbios_name0='TRISTSCCM-PS'
GROUP BY Netbios_Name0, RuleName, RuleDescription, prereifiedvalue, complianceState,v_cirules.CI_ID,v_CIRules.Max_id,Criteria
```

RESULTS

```
Max_id  (No column name)    Netbios_Name0   RuleName    RuleDescription prereifiedvalue complianceState
16780130    4   TRISTSCCM-PS    OS Hardening: Account Lockout Policy - Account lockout duration Applicable /Account lockout duration Must equal to 10   NULL    1
16780130    8   TRISTSCCM-PS    OS Hardening: Account Lockout Policy - Account lockout duration Applicable /Account lockout duration Must equal to 10   NULL    1
16780130    12  TRISTSCCM-PS    OS Hardening: Account Lockout Policy - Account lockout duration Applicable /Account lockout duration Must equal to 10   NULL    1
```

Comment: use having with ruleId = max(ruleid)

Comment: You are using a left join after 2 inner joins, it would return more than one row. Try using inner join instead and try to re run the query, or use row_num function to return max row

Comment: Hi, Thank you. When i remove 3rd join nothing changed.

Comment: Hi,

you can post some sample data for all tables then it will be helpful.

If not, in your case you are taking max rule id in a particular group so rule id will be repeated for multiple groups. 

better the take max rule id and use it subsequent queries with CTE

Comment: You have different `CIVersion` values here - if you could aggregate these out (like `max(CIVersion) as CIVersion`) and remove it from `group by` clause too, then probably you could get correct results.

Answer (score 0):

```
USE CM_T01
SELECT Max_id, CIVersion, Netbios_Name0, RuleName, RuleDescription, Criteria, prereifiedvalue, complianceState
FROM v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT CI_ID,Rule_ID, Rulename,  RuleDescription, MAX(Rule_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY Rulename) AS Max_id
from v_cirules
where rulename like '%Account lockout duration%'
group by Rule_ID,RuleName, RuleDescription) as v_CIRules 
ON v_CIRules.CI_ID = v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus.CI_ID
INNER JOIN v_R_System 
ON v_R_System.ResourceID = v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus.ItemKey
LEFT JOIN v_CICurrentRuleDetail 
ON v_CICurrentRuleDetail.CurrentComplianceStatusID = v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus.CI_CurrentComplianceStatusID
GROUP BY CIVersion, Netbios_Name0, RuleName, RuleDescription, Criteria, prereifiedvalue, complianceState
```

Comment: There is a problem near MAX(Rule_ID), Message is; 

"Incorrect syntax near '('. expecting '), EXPECT, or UNION"

Comment: Repaired please try the run the sub query to test it out. Do you understand why its needed?

Comment: Thanks but there is another problem with these line; ON v_CIRules.CI_ID = v_CI_CurrentComplianceStatus.CI_ID

--------------------------------

Invalid column name 'CI_ID'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15

Comment: I put the CI_ID in to the sub-select.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column 'v_cirules.CI_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
Invalid column name 'Criteria'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name 'Criteria'.

Comment: So you must put all the columns to the sub select and the sob group by group by what you want to use in the main select.

Comment: Tried but not worked, i am not dba :) this is what i was able to do.

Comment: I see then to be faster can you put 3 row of each table in excel with the column what you use the id must be match other columns can be blank. So i can import to my db and test it out.

Comment: Ok I have changed query, but i see we have to get max for civersion column too. 

And Results are like this, we must select only one which is CIversion 12 (MAX)

16780130 8 TRISTSCCM-PS OS Hardening: Account Lockout Policy - Account lockout duration Applicable /Account lockout duration Must equal to 10 NULL 1
16780130 12 TRISTSCCM-PS OS Hardening: Account Lockout Policy - Account lockout duration Applicable /Account lockout duration Must equal to 10 NULL 1

Comment: If CI Version not important then you only need to go back your original select delete CIVersion from group by and modify in select to max(CIVersion)

Comment: Thanks, i did as you wrote. And i have edited my first question as you want. You can see last update of query in my first question. But i guess i need to change first select query as you did (Over partition etc.) But whole query little bit hard for me and i could'nt get unique values so far.